# Whats is the meaning of this equality in the complex plane?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

let $w(z)$ be a complex function and $dz$ the increasing of $z$, prove that

$dw = w_{z}dz + w_{\overset{-}{z}}d\overset{-}{z}$

i'm totaly lost in this relation because i can't find a way to define the increasing of a complex number and let $w(z) = u+iv$, whats the meaning of $dw$? i just know what is $dw/dz$ and $dw/d\overset{-}{z}$.